# CAS Single Sign Out not worked in drupal

Tags: drupal, single-sign-on, cas

I have:

1. configured CAS that works correctly.
2. configured Drupal whit cas module and sign in using CAS correctly.

but when I click log out in drupal I just loged out from drupal not from cas.

is there any special configuration for log out? in drupal admin there is just one checkbox:

"Enable CAS Single Sign Out (CAS server 3.1 or greater)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the CAS Logout menu where you administer your menus.  Use this as your logout menu instead of the drupal provided one.

Comment: Hi @Dave could you please explain it . In the drupal menu section there is no CAS logout menu

Comment: I have found the menu those are at admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation